# unable to access gitlab.com/user/project.git Send failure Connection was reset

Tags: authentication, gitlab

I get an error message unable to access `gitlab.com/user/project.git Send failure Connection was reset`.

My `.ssh/config` file looks like

```
# GITLAB
Host gitlab.com
   HostName gitlab.com
   PreferredAuthentications publickey
   IdentityFile ~\\.ssh\\id_rsa
```

I have `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` files. I didnot change ssh keys on gitlab since the time connection worked. Reinstalling git didnot fix the issue.

How to fix this?

Everything worked before windows update. Here is the output of `ssh -vvv git@gitlab.com`

```
C:\Users\user\.ssh>ssh -vvv git@gitlab.com
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.6p1, LibreSSL 3.4.3
debug1: Reading configuration data C:\\Users\\user/.ssh/config
debug1: C:\\Users\\user/.ssh/config line 2: Applying options for gitlab.com
debug1: Reading configuration data __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/ssh_config
debug1: __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/ssh_config line 2: Applying options for gitlab.com
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> 'C:\\Users\\user/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug2: resolving "gitlab.com" port 22
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to gitlab.com [172.65.251.78] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\user/\\\\.ssh\\\\id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\user/\\\\.ssh\\\\id_rsa-cert type 0
debug1: load_public_identity_files: key C:\\Users\\user/\\\\.ssh\\\\id_rsa-cert type RSA is not a certificate
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\user/.ssh/id_rsa_lab type 0
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\user/.ssh/id_rsa_lab-cert type 0
debug1: load_public_identity_files: key C:\\Users\\user/.ssh/id_rsa_lab-cert type RSA is not a certificate
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.6
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version GitLab-SSHD
debug1: compat_banner: no match: GitLab-SSHD
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to gitlab.com:22 as 'git'
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file C:\\Users\\user/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys_file: loaded 1 keys from gitlab.com
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts error:2
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2 error:2
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none
debug2: compression stoc: none
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:HbW3g8zUjNSksFbqTiUWPWg2Bq1x8xdGUrliXFzSnUw
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file C:\\Users\\user/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys_file: loaded 1 keys from gitlab.com
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts error:2
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2 error:2
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host 'gitlab.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in C:\\Users\\user/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\user/\\\\.ssh\\\\id_rsa RSA SHA256:GNhOmB27ubgyTu1/VCL9otabmtd2KmGD1A5GLQxkDP0 explicit
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\user/.ssh/id_rsa_lab RSA SHA256:GNhOmB27ubgyTu1/VCL9otabmtd2KmGD1A5GLQxkDP0
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss>
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: ping@openssh.com (unrecognised)
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred publickey
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred:
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: C:\\Users\\user/\\\\.ssh\\\\id_rsa RSA SHA256:GNhOmB27ubgyTu1/VCL9otabmtd2KmGD1A5GLQxkDP0 explicit
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: C:\\Users\\user/\\\\.ssh\\\\id_rsa RSA SHA256:GNhOmB27ubgyTu1/VCL9otabmtd2KmGD1A5GLQxkDP0 explicit
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:GNhOmB27ubgyTu1/VCL9otabmtd2KmGD1A5GLQxkDP0
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: signing using rsa-sha2-512 SHA256:GNhOmB27ubgyTu1/VCL9otabmtd2KmGD1A5GLQxkDP0
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 52
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to gitlab.com ([172.65.251.78]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: filesystem full
debug1: ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_INPUT is supported. Reading the VTSequence from console
debug3: This windows OS supports conpty
debug1: ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING is supported. Console supports the ansi parsing
debug3: Successfully set console output code page from:65001 to 65001
debug3: Successfully set console input code page from:866 to 65001
debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 2097152 rmax 32768
debug3: receive packet: type 100
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 100 id 0
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
debug3: Successfully set console output code page from 65001 to 65001
debug3: Successfully set console input code page from 65001 to 866
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
debug3: receive packet: type 96
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
Welcome to GitLab, @user!
debug3: receive packet: type 98
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
debug2: chan_shutdown_read: channel 0: (i0 o1 sock -1 wfd 4 efd 6 [write])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to add a file `c:\users\%username%\.ssh\config` with the following content

```
# GITLAB
Host gitlab.com
   HostName gitlab.com
   PreferredAuthentications publickey
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

UserKnownHostsFile ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```